# Looking for either a tv show or tv movie movie from the early 2000s where blonde teen was lost on a desert planet

Tags: story-identification

The main character had blonde hair and was in his late teens. I think him and his family were stuck on a different planet that was like a desert. He befriended a girl that was dressed almost like she was in a tribe or something.

I think I watched this on the Disney channel in the U.K. back in like 2002. But it isn't a Disney show or movie, I've checked.

Comment: Interesting, but this is super light on details. Can you remember _anything_ else? Check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: This is making me think of 'Otherworld' but the teen on that was dark haired - his sister was blonde